# Cerificate issue in Jenkins-Plugins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am running jenkins inside docker container. My jenkins image is jenkins/jekins:lts-jdk11. My container is up & running but i could not install any of the plugins, not even a single plugin. It has error of certificate-

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)

What should i do?

I have already tried creating self-signed certificate and importing it but it does not work. Java SDK list in jenkins conatiner-
openjdk 11.0.20 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.20+8 (build 11.0.20+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.20+8 (build 11.0.20+8, mixed mode)

Is jenkins need CA certs only not self signed?